# Best features for music classifications

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, audio-analysis

I'm trying to develop an application to classify music in to probably favorite or not probably favorite by training a Neural network from music which are already marked as favorite by user himself. I never done audio analysis before so I know almost nothing about it. **To make this an accurate classification model what features do I need to include in my dataset of music**. 
eg:- decibel values , frequency values, length of the audio

thank you

Comment: you will probably want an encoding of the actual frequency domain of the music itself using an RNN in addition to these other features given you have enough data

Comment: This is very close to a recommendation problem. The most likely to be classified as a favorite is probably also what would be the primarily recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spectrograms are a useful technique for visualising the spectrum of frequencies of a sound and how they vary during a very short period of time. You can use a similar technique known as Mel-Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC) as features for the dataset.

[image: MFCC]

You can use [Librosa's mfcc()](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) function which generates an MFCC from time series audio data to make the task a lot easier

Answer (score 2):

Start by using the music feature extractors from Essentia. You can for instance use their [commandline tool](https://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/streaming_extractor_music.html). This provides you with tons of low-level audio features (30+ types), as well rhythm (6+ feature types) and tonal (6+ features).
You can also do the same with the Python bindings.